# Powershell 'Permisson Denied' when trying to read files in a newly created folder

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a directory with a bunch of text files in it. I am creating a new folder inside of the directory to move the text files into and when I am done merging them I want to only move the output file back out to the original directory.

When I create the folder and move the text files into it, it will not let me go inside of the folder and perform my actions. I am stuck on this.

My code:

```
$Path = '*.RemoveFirst\txt'
$PathDump ='C:RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
$Output = 'C:RemoveFirst\TestingFile.txt'


if(!(Test-Path -Path $PathDump)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $PathDump
}
elseif (Test-Path -Path $PathDump){
    Move-Item $Path -Destination $PathDump # move (not copy) files into new directory to concat
    Get-Item $PathDump | ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content $_ | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
        Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
        Add-Content $OutPut
        }
    Write-Host 'This already exists'
}
```

Comment: The If/ElseIf is strange.  If PathDump does not exist then it creates it then that's it.  Code in ElseIf does not run.  Did you mean to run the code in ElseIf once the folder is created?  If so, change the ElseIf to just another (new) If block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths seem wrong. `$Path` should be `'C:\RemoveFirst\*.txt'` and the other two paths you define are missing a backslash after the drive colon.

Next, I don't see the logic in the `elseif` because when you first test and conclude the `$PathDump` path does not exist, you create it. That should be enough to continue with the code, no testing if the path exists using elsif needed .

Try

```
$Path     = 'C:\RemoveFirst\*.txt'
$PathDump = 'C:\RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
$Output   = 'C:\RemoveFirst\TestingFile.txt'

if(!(Test-Path -Path $PathDump)) {
    # create the folder if it does not yet exist
    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory $PathDump
}
# move all *.txt items from 'C:\RemoveFirst\txt' to 'C:\RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
Move-Item $Path -Destination $PathDump # move (not copy) files into new directory to concat
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathDump -Filter '*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-Content | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
    Add-Content -Path $OutPut
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Get-Item`, which gets the destination folder in this case. You can't `Get-Content` on a folder. Try something like this:

```
$Path = '*.RemoveFirst\txt'
$PathDump ='C:RemoveFirst\DumpARoo'
$Output = 'C:RemoveFirst\TestingFile.txt'


if(!(Test-Path -Path $PathDump)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory $PathDump
}
elseif (Test-Path -Path $PathDump){
    Move-Item $Path -Destination $PathDump # move (not copy) files into new directory to concat
    # Add the -Recurse switch to Get-ChildItem if you need subfolders
    Get-ChildItem $PathDump -File | ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content $_ | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
        Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
        Add-Content $OutPut
        }
    Write-Host 'This already exists'
}
```

Comment: Nvm it creates it but it doesn't contain anything because it says my text files doesn't exist

Comment: Is `$Path` really correct? What's your intention there? Is `$PathDump` really correct? If `RemoveFirst` is off the root, you should specify that as `C:\RemoveFIrst` - same with `$Output`

Comment: they are correct, I just shortened them for the sake of the question because they are quite long